# Do partial derivation respect to velocity and total derivation respect to time commute?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, time, differentiation, commutator

Imagine we have a function of position $x^i$ and velocity $v^i$ $f(x,v)$. Position and velocity are both functions of time $t$. If the function doesn't depend explicitely on time, then we have the identity

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt} f(x,v)= v^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} f(x,v)
\end{equation}
Now imagine we define a new function

\begin{equation}
G(x,v)=v^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} f(x,v)=\frac{d}{dt} f(x,v)
\end{equation}

and we want to derive $G$ respect to velocity. If we derive it using the first equation we get

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial v^j}G(x,v)=\delta^{ij} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} f(x,v)+v^i\frac{\partial}{\partial v^j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} f(x,v)
\end{equation}
%
If we derive using the second equation instead we get

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial v^j}G(x,v)=\frac{\partial}{\partial v^j}\frac{d}{dt} f(x,v)
\end{equation}
Now, I thought that these two derivatives commuted but that can't be right because then we would get

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial v^j}G(x,v)&=\frac{\partial}{\partial v^j}\frac{d}{dt} f(x,v) \\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial v^j}f(x,v) \\
&=v^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i }\frac{\partial}{\partial v^j} f(x,v)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

which is only the second term we obtained with the first identity. Does this mean that the commutator between $\frac{d}{dt}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial v^i}$ is

\begin{equation}
[\frac{\partial}{\partial v^i},\frac{d}{dt}]=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} ?
\end{equation}

Comment: OP's last eq. is correct. Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/613932/2451

Comment: The first equality is wrong. A full time-derivative brings 2 factors.