# Notation and Terminology Questions from Schwartz' QFT Book

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, differentiation, notation, variational-calculus

I am finding some of the notation confusing in Chapter 3 on Classical Field Theory in Schwartz' QFT book a bit confusing.

1. First off, on page 34 he defines a translation of a field to first order as
   $$\phi(x) \rightarrow \phi(x+\xi) = \phi(x) +\xi^{\nu}\partial_v \phi(x)+...\tag{3.29}$$
   So good so far, but then he writes
   $$\frac{\delta\phi}{\delta \xi^{\nu}} = \partial_v\phi.\tag{3.30}$$
   To me that looks like an ordinary partial derivative, **so I don't get why he writes it as $\frac{\delta\phi}{\delta \xi^{\nu}}$ instead of $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial \xi^{\nu}}$**.
2. My second question is that he later writes

   > $$\frac{\delta\mathscr{L}}{\delta \xi^{\nu}} = \partial_{\nu}\mathscr{L}.\tag{3.31}$$
   > Since this is a total derivative,
   > $$ \delta S = \int d^4x\delta\mathscr{L}=\xi^{\nu}\int d^4x\partial_{\nu}\mathscr{L}=0.$$

   I wouldn't interpret $\partial_{\nu}\mathscr{L}$ as a total derivative. **Wouldn't that typically be the total divergence $d_{_\nu}\mathscr{L}$?**

He seems to use the term loosely.

Comment: "*He seems to use the term loosely.*" Welcome to the wonderful world of physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes. OP is right.  The LHS of eq. (3.30) is supposed to be a partial derivative.
2. Yes. OP is right. The RHS of eq. (3.31) is supposed to be a total derivative.

See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/321668/2451) related Phys.SE post.